# How do i locate swi-prolog directory in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, swi-prolog

I downloaded SWI-Prolog in Ubuntu, how can I locate the swipl directory/folder it generated?

I have tried using the `find` command from the root specifying type -d but no luck, the terminal exited.

Comment: What do you get if you type on a command-line terminal `which swipl`?

Comment: thanks, this worked I got /usr/bin/swipl, I didn't know about this.

Comment: `find` is slow, `locate swipl` would have been faster would `which` not work